# bpftrace: uprobe target file does not exist or is not executable

Tags: linux, address-sanitizer, bpf, dynamic-analysis, bcc-bpf

I want to use bpftrace to trace functions inside libasan library, which is inside /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.

However

`sudo bpftrace -e 'uretprobe:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4: __interceptor_malloc { printf("pid: %d, malloc %p\n", pid, retval); }'`

gives error: `uprobe target file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4' does not exist or is not executable`

I have tried: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib"` but it does not help.

How can make the library executable for bpftrace? I need it to trace allocations done in a Firefox process. Thanks!

EDIT: I just found out that the permission on libasan is -rw-r--r--, which means it is indeed not executable. How should I make it executable?

Comment: you need to include the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, right? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, good point. I tried: ```export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
``` but bpftrace gives the same error.

Comment: you're using tools I'm not familiar with. I would look for developer forums for those tools. Good luck.

Comment: re permissions. Probably required. And in any case, it can't hurt to try it ;-) . Good luc,k.

Comment: On my system (Ubuntu 18.04), `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4` is not a binary but a symbolic link towards `libasan.so.4.0.0` in the same directory. If you have a similar setup, maybe try to pass the latter instead of a symbolic link?

Comment: thanks. I fixed it by doing `chmod +x libasan.so.4.0.0`

Comment: can you answer and mark it as answered?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by doing chmod +x libasan.so.4.0.0